# Set a display from block to none in my tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my first post and i hope you can help me out.
I have this code, but i'm trying to set the display of each tabs from block to none. For example if i click on CM it should changes the display of table-2 into a display:block; and set the display of the other 2 in none, and the size-guide__tabs--selected in the one i selected.
I tried with some Javascript but i'm new to it so i had no success..

I know I ask you a lot, but an example is enough for me to try to solve the remaining part by myself.

```html
<div class="content-asset">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.hbc.com/chad/bay/editorial/plugins/saksoff5th/size-guide/off5th-size-guide-template-0000-00-00-main-2.0.1.css">
  <div id="dsg-editorial" class="dsg-editorial dsg-en">
    <section class="size-guide">
      <div class="size-guide__tabs">
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--header">
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-left">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-1 size-guide__tabs--selected">
              <span>Measurements</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-2">
              <span>Size Conversion</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-right" style="display: flex;">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--inches size-guide__tabs--selected">
              <span>IN</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--centimiters">
              <span>CM</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--content">
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-1" style="display: block;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32" - 32.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">35"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">33.5" - 34"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">36"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34.5" - 35"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">37"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">35.5" - 36"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">38"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36.5" - 37"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">39"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">37.5" - 38"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">40.5"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38.5" - 39.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">42"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">41.5" - 42.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">43.5"</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">81 - 82.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">89</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">85 - 86.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">91.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">87.5 - 89</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">94</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">90 - 91.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">96.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">92.5 - 94</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">99</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">95 - 96.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">103</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">98 - 100</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">106.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">105 - 108</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">110.5</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-3" style="display: none;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">US Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">France</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Italy</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">UK</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Japan</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">00</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">30</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">0</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">7</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">9</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">11</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">13</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">48</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">15</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">50</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">18</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">17</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Solved using Darshan Gada answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with
Little HTML Improvements required and Javascript code.

This JS code will handle the toggles of all 3 tables simultaneously. :)

```js
const cmClass = "size-guide__tabs--centimiters";
const inClass = "size-guide__tabs--inches";
const selected = "size-guide__tabs--selected"
const measureClass = "size-guide__tabs-1";
const sizeClass = "size-guide__tabs-2"
var inTable = document.getElementsByClassName("size-guide__table-1");
var cmTable = document.getElementsByClassName("size-guide__table-2");
var sizeTable = document.getElementsByClassName("size-guide__table-3");
var cmToggle = document.getElementsByClassName(cmClass);
var inToggle = document.getElementsByClassName(inClass);
var sizeToggle = document.getElementsByClassName(sizeClass);
var measureToggle = document.getElementsByClassName(measureClass);

function toggleMeasure(elm) {
  if (elm.classList.contains(cmClass)) {
    cmTable[0].style.display = 'block';
    inTable[0].style.display = 'none';
    sizeTable[0].style.display = 'none';
    cmToggle[0].classList.add(selected);
    inToggle[0].classList.remove(selected);
  } else if (elm.classList.contains(inClass) || elm.classList.contains(measureClass)) {
    inTable[0].style.display = 'block';
    cmTable[0].style.display = 'none';
    sizeTable[0].style.display = 'none';
    inToggle[0].classList.add(selected);
    cmToggle[0].classList.remove(selected);
    measureToggle[0].classList.add(selected);
    sizeToggle[0].classList.remove(selected);
  } else if (elm.classList.contains(sizeClass)) {
    cmTable[0].style.display = 'none';
    inTable[0].style.display = 'none';
    sizeTable[0].style.display = 'block';
    inToggle[0].classList.add(selected);
    cmToggle[0].classList.remove(selected);
    sizeToggle[0].classList.add(selected);
    measureToggle[0].classList.remove(selected);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-asset">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.hbc.com/chad/bay/editorial/plugins/saksoff5th/size-guide/off5th-size-guide-template-0000-00-00-main-2.0.1.css">
  <div id="dsg-editorial" class="dsg-editorial dsg-en">
    <section class="size-guide">
      <div class="size-guide__tabs">
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--header">
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-left">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-1 size-guide__tabs--selected" onclick="toggleMeasure(this)">
              <span>Measurements</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-2" onclick="toggleMeasure(this)">
              <span>Size Conversion</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-right" style="display: flex;">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--inches size-guide__tabs--selected" onclick="toggleMeasure(this)">
              <span>IN</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--centimiters" onclick="toggleMeasure(this)">
              <span>CM</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--content">
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-1" style="display: block;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32" - 32.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">35"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">33.5" - 34"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">36"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34.5" - 35"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">37"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">35.5" - 36"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">38"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36.5" - 37"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">39"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">37.5" - 38"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">40.5"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38.5" - 39.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">42"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">41.5" - 42.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">43.5"</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">81 - 82.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">89</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">85 - 86.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">91.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">87.5 - 89</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">94</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">90 - 91.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">96.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">92.5 - 94</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">99</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">95 - 96.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">103</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">98 - 100</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">106.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">105 - 108</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">110.5</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-3" style="display: none;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">US Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">France</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Italy</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">UK</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Japan</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">00</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">30</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">0</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">7</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">9</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">11</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">13</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">48</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">15</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">50</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">18</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">17</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU MAN!! THANKS!
The code was so clear that I implemented alone the feature that i wanted :
When clicked on Size conversion the In Cm in the header right should be removed. 
I did this : 
1: added const headerRight = "size-guide__tabs--header-right";
2: added var headerRightToggle = document.getElementsByClassName(headerRight);
3: in the else if (elm.classList.contains(sizeClass)) {
    headerRightToggle[0].style.display = 'none';
and in the other one headerRightToggle[0].style.display = 'flex';

It completely works.

Comment: @HereToLearn Can you please mark this answer as Correct and Upvote it. :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

1. Add a class of display none on all tabs except the tab which is clicked.
2. As for this demo I added `onclick` on 3 elements just for demonstration

```js
function openTab(tab) {
  let tables = document.querySelectorAll(".size-guide__table");
  tables.forEach((table)=> {
    table.classList.add("displayNone");
  });
  
  document.getElementById(tab).classList.add("displayBlock");
  document.getElementById(tab).classList.remove("displayNone");
}
```

```css
.displayBlock {
  display: block !important;
}
.displayNone{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-asset">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.hbc.com/chad/bay/editorial/plugins/saksoff5th/size-guide/off5th-size-guide-template-0000-00-00-main-2.0.1.css">
  <div id="dsg-editorial" class="dsg-editorial dsg-en">
    <section class="size-guide">
      <div class="size-guide__tabs">
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--header">
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-left">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-1 size-guide__tabs--selected">
              <span>Measurements</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-2" onclick="openTab('table_1')">
              <span>Size Conversion</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-right" style="display: flex;">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--inches size-guide__tabs--selected"  onclick="openTab('table_2')">
              <span>IN</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--centimiters"  onclick="openTab('table_3')">
              <span>CM</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--content">
          <div class="size-guide__table displayBlock size-guide__table-1" id="table_1">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32" - 32.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">35"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">33.5" - 34"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">36"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34.5" - 35"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">37"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">35.5" - 36"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">38"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36.5" - 37"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">39"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">37.5" - 38"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">40.5"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38.5" - 39.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">42"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">41.5" - 42.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">43.5"</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table displayBlock size-guide__table-2" id="table_2">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">81 - 82.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">89</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">85 - 86.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">91.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">87.5 - 89</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">94</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">90 - 91.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">96.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">92.5 - 94</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">99</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">95 - 96.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">103</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">98 - 100</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">106.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">105 - 108</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">110.5</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table displayBlock size-guide__table-3" id="table_3">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">US Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">France</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Italy</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">UK</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Japan</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">00</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">30</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">0</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">7</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">9</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">11</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">13</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">48</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">15</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">50</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">18</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">17</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

[Working **Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cw70pxyh/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by adding `data` attribute to the html element you want to target.

In your case I added `data-target` attribute.

In your html I **removed** the `span tag` inside `a` element to avoid event bubbling upon clicking the target element and specified the  `data-attribute`. I also added a `size-guide__tab` class to all tabs so I can target them in js. All applies to the tabs `Measurement, Size Conversion, IN, and CM`.

```
<a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-2 size-guide__tab" data-target="cm">
    CM
</a>
```

Then I also added the `data-target` attribute to the size guide tables.

```
<div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-1" data-target="IN" style="display: block;">
 //...
</div>
```

And lastly, added the script

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.size-guide__tab');
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.size-guide__table');

tabs.forEach((tab) => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     const targetName = e.target.dataset.target;
     const parent = e.target.parentElement;
     const targetTable = document.querySelector(`div[data-target=${targetName}]`);
     
    // remove the size-guide__tabs--selected class on all children then attach to only clicked tab
    Array.from(parent.children).forEach(child => child.classList.remove('size-guide__tabs--selected'));
    
    //attach class to clicked tab
    e.target.classList.add('size-guide__tabs--selected');
    
    // since you only have the IN and CM options, we need to make sure that the target 
    table exists
    if (targetTable) {
      // hide all table guide
      tables.forEach(table => table.style.display = 'none');
      // then show only the target table
      targetTable.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```
<div class="content-asset">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.hbc.com/chad/bay/editorial/plugins/saksoff5th/size-guide/off5th-size-guide-template-0000-00-00-main-2.0.1.css">
  <div id="dsg-editorial" class="dsg-editorial dsg-en">
    <section class="size-guide">
      <div class="size-guide__tabs">
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--header">
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-left">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-1 size-guide__tab size-guide__tabs--selected" data-target="measurement">
              Measurement
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-2 size-guide__tab" data-target="size_conversion">
             Size Conversion
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-right" style="display: flex;">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--inches size-guide__tab size-guide__tabs--selected" data-target="IN">
              IN
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--centimiters size-guide__tab" data-target="CM">
              CM
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--content">
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-1" data-target="IN" style="display: block;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32" - 32.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">35"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">33.5" - 34"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">36"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34.5" - 35"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">37"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">35.5" - 36"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">38"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36.5" - 37"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">39"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">37.5" - 38"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">40.5"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38.5" - 39.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">42"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">41.5" - 42.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">43.5"</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-2" data-target="CM" style="display: none;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">81 - 82.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">89</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">85 - 86.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">91.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">87.5 - 89</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">94</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">90 - 91.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">96.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">92.5 - 94</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">99</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">95 - 96.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">103</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">98 - 100</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">106.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">105 - 108</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">110.5</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-3" style="display: none;">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">US Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">France</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Italy</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">UK</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Japan</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">00</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">30</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">0</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">7</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">9</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">11</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">13</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">48</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">15</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">50</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">18</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">17</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

You can see the demo [HERE](https://codepen.io/jgudo/pen/oNzzVdX?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Why are there four buttons, but only three tables to display?

```js
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.size-guide__tabs--header-left a');
let tabs_ = document.querySelectorAll('.size-guide__tabs--header-right a');
let blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.size-guide__table');

Array.from(tabs).forEach(function(tab, index) {
    tab.onclick = function() {
      Array.from(tabs).forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove('size-guide__tabs--selected'));
      this.classList.add('size-guide__tabs--selected');
      
      Array.from(blocks).forEach(block => block.classList.remove('size-guide__table_active'));
      blocks[index].classList.add('size-guide__table_active');
    }
});

Array.from(tabs_).forEach(function(tab_, index) {
    tab_.onclick = function() {
      Array.from(tabs_).forEach(tab_ => tab_.classList.remove('size-guide__tabs--selected'));
      this.classList.add('size-guide__tabs--selected');
      
      Array.from(blocks).forEach(block => block.classList.remove('size-guide__table_active'));
      blocks[2].classList.add('size-guide__table_active');
    }
});
```

```css
.size-guide__table {
  display: none!important;
}

.size-guide__table_active {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-asset">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.hbc.com/chad/bay/editorial/plugins/saksoff5th/size-guide/off5th-size-guide-template-0000-00-00-main-2.0.1.css">
  <div id="dsg-editorial" class="dsg-editorial dsg-en">
    <section class="size-guide">
      <div class="size-guide__tabs">
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--header">
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-left">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-1 size-guide__tabs--selected">
              <span>Measurements</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs-2">
              <span>Size Conversion</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__tabs--header-right" style="display: flex;">
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--inches size-guide__tabs--selected">
              <span>IN</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="size-guide__tabs--centimiters">
              <span>CM</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="size-guide__tabs--content">
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-1 size-guide__table_active">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32" - 32.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">24" - 25"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">35"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">33.5" - 34"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">25" - 26"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">36"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34.5" - 35"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">26" - 27"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">37"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">35.5" - 36"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">27" - 28"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">38"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36.5" - 37"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">28" - 29"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">39"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">37.5" - 38"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">29.5" - 30.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">40.5"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38.5" - 39.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">31" - 32"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">42"</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">41.5" - 42.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">32.5" - 33.5"</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">43.5"</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-2">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">Bust</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Natural Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">Low Waist</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Hips</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">81 - 82.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">61 - 63.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">89</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">85 - 86.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">63.5 - 66</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">91.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">87.5 - 89</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">66 - 68.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">94</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">90 - 91.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">68.5 - 71</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">96.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">92.5 - 94</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">71 - 73.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">99</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">95 - 96.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">75 - 77.5</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">103</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">98 - 100</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">79 - 81</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">106.5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">105 - 108</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">82.5 - 85</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">110.5</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="size-guide__table size-guide__table-3">
            <div class="size-guide__table--mobile">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="size-guide__table--container">
              <div class="size-guide__table--header">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">Alpha</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">US Size</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">France</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">Italy</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">UK</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">Japan</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">00</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">30</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">0</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">32</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XS</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">2</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">34</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">S</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">4</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">36</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">7</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">6</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">38</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">9</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">M</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">8</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">40</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">11</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">L</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">10</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">42</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">13</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">12</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">44</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">48</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">16</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">15</div>
              </div>
              <div class="size-guide__table--row">
                <div class="table__row-cell-1">XXL</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-2">14</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-3">46</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-4">50</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-5">18</div>
                <div class="table__row-cell-6">17</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are 4 Buttons because the Measurements has IN / CM tables displayed under her (so you can switch between In and Cm under that selected item), and Size Conversion is one single table displayed.